# How do I implement a responsive AdSense unit that shows as 728x90 on desktop

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense, google-ads, advertising

I have a Website built with this WordPress theme: http://planetshine.net/demo/goliath-news/home-iv/ which has a 728x90 Ad on the top.   That ad is showing fine on desktop but on mobile it's getting cropped.

Someone told me that I can use Responsive Ad Units https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?visit_id=0-636119602603066720-1220120413&hl=en&ref_topic=3641113&rd=1 but I couldn't get them to work.   How do I implement an Adsense ad that shows the large size on desktop but a smaller as on mobile?